# Citavi exports Greek letters as \textgreek{a}

Tags: fonts, bibtex

I am working with `Citavi` to manage my literature and it exports Greek letters as `\textgreek{a}` or `{b}` or `{g}` which doesn't work for me. I found out that you need the package `babel` with the `greek` language and I am using it like this now.

```
\usepackage[greek, ngerman]{babel}
```

Now I am getting another error concerning a metric file, however:

`! Font \LGR/phv/m/sl/10.95=nullfont not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.`

I have no idea what to make of it. I guess I have to find this file somewhere but I have no idea how to get it or how to install it. I am using `miktex` and `texniccenter`.

Comment: For some reason, the font used is *Helvetica* (`phv`). I don't think it has Greek letters. Replace it with *TeX Gyre Heros* (`qhv`).

Comment: @Bernard TeX Gyre Heros doesn’t, either.

Comment: @Davislor: The opentype version does have greek letters (checked with NexusFont).

Comment: @Bernard The OpenType version has unaccented Greek letters, and can support a subset of modern Greek, but not for example ΐ. Its Greek support seems to be more for math mode in `unicode-math` or `mathspec`.

Comment: @Bernard But `qhv` doesn’t, and cannot be used here, as an 8-bit Greek font, because it has no LGR font.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change how your tools export citations, it would be better to simply export the Greek letters as UTF-8. That’s the default encoding for all TeX engines now.

Failing that, the `alphabeta` package allows you to use `\alpha`, `\beta`, etc. in text mode.  This, unlike the Teubner version of `textgreek`, will be compatible with LuaTeX and XeTeX.

Failing that, the solutions to use TeX Gyre Heros will fail in PDFTeX, since that font has no Greek letters either, and so will `helvet` on most systems.

You can, however, declare a `substututefont`.  Nimbus Sans is very similar to Helvetica, but is currently broken because of a typo in the filename `LGRNimbuSans.fd`.  So you might use Noto Sans:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\usepackage{tgheros}

\renewcommand*\familydefault\sfdefault

\substitutefont{LGR}{\sfdefault}{NotoSans-OsF}

\begin{document}
Testing \textgreek{a}, \textgreek{b} and \textgreek{g}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Noto Sans sample]

Answer (score 0):

I hope to have understood the question. Here you can use helvetica (`helvet`) font with greek letters "via `\textgreek{a}`".

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage[greek, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 

\begin{document}
My test with helvetica font and \textalpha\, or \textepsilon
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The Greek letters are defaulting to `cmr`, because `helvet` does not contain any LGR font.